# How to add a Interface type Object to list where Interface type has Generic types

Tags: c#, .net, interface, generic-type-parameters

How to add an Interface to list where Interface type has Generic types?

Below are the code snippet for the same

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public interface ITest<TMessageKey, TEventMessage, TProducerSetting, TProducerClient>
    {
        Task ProcesMessage(Func<TMessageKey, TEventMessage, TProducerSetting, IResult<TEventMessage>> message);
    }

    public class Test<TMessageKey, TEventMessage, TProducerSetting, TProducerClient> : ITest<TMessageKey, TEventMessage, TProducerSetting, TProducerClient>
    {
        public async Task ProcesMessage(Func<TMessageKey, TEventMessage, TProducerSetting, IResult<TEventMessage>> message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processed...");
        }
    }


    public interface IResult<TEventMessage>
    {
        TEventMessage ProcessedMessage { get; set; }
        bool Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result<TEventMessage> : IResult<TEventMessage>
    {
        public TEventMessage ProcessedMessage { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IType { }
    public class Message { }
    public class Message1 : Message { }
    public class Message2 : Message { }
    public class Message3 : Message { }
    public class TestProducerSetting { }
    public class SomeClient { }

    public class Execute
    {
        private List<ITest<string, Message, TestProducerSetting, SomeClient>> lst = new();

        public void TestMethod()
        {
            ITest<string, Message1, TestProducerSetting, SomeClient> test1 = new Test<string, Message1, TestProducerSetting, SomeClient>();
            ITest<string, Message2, TestProducerSetting, SomeClient> test2 = new Test<string, Message2, TestProducerSetting, SomeClient>();
            ITest<string, Message3, TestProducerSetting, SomeClient> test3 = new Test<string, Message3, TestProducerSetting, SomeClient>();

            var res1 = test1.ProcesMessage(Method1);
            var res2 = test2.ProcesMessage(Method2);
            var res3 = test3.ProcesMessage(Method3);

            //Compile time error comes here
            lst.Add(test1);
            lst.Add(test2);
            lst.Add(test3);
        }

        private IResult<Message1> Method1(string messageKey, Message1 message, TestProducerSetting setting)
        {
            return new Result<Message1> { ProcessedMessage = message, Status = true };
        }

        private IResult<Message2> Method2(string messageKey, Message2 message, TestProducerSetting setting)
        {
            return new Result<Message2> { ProcessedMessage = message, Status = true };
        }

        private IResult<Message3> Method3(string messageKey, Message3 message, TestProducerSetting setting)
        {
            return new Result<Message3> { ProcessedMessage = message, Status = true };
        }
    }
}
```

In real time the `test1`, `test2` and `test3` objects are created in the loop.
Note that "ProcesMessage" takes the Func input where TEventMessage in input as well as part of the return type as well. I was not able to achieve this using covariance and contravariance.

Please note that, just for the queries I created the object manually.
Is it possible to resolve it?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you are doing inside `Method1`, `Method2` and `Method3`. Do you really need to know the type of message in there? The definition of `Message` is incomplete so it's hard to understand the intent.

Comment: Message will act as just a base class. And Method1, Method2 and Method3 will have some business logic. The message parameter in the Methods get converts to some other format and pushed messages to some queues. in case of any failures the original messages will get returned for error handling

Comment: @KirkWoll I will post error message.

Comment: @KirkWoll I took  little long time to post a error message.

The below error was getting while adding to the list..


cannot convert from 'MyNamespace.ITest<string, **MyNamespace.Message1**, MyNamespace.TestProducerSetting, MyNamespace.SomeClient>' to 'MyNamespace.ITest<string, **MyNamespace.Message**, MyNamespace.TestProducerSetting, TMyNamespace.SomeClient>